# UIView tableview cell shadow glitching since xcode 6.3 /ios8.3

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, shadow

I've been having an issue where the shadows in my UIView in a custom cell arent rendering properly first time round, but when the cells redraw by scrolling, then they are correct again.

I hadn't seen this happen in 8.2 and only after I updated my toolchange to 6.3/8.3

Incorrect
https://cldup.com/Fwl4aMkk4P.png

Correct
https://cldup.com/O_vPA1jrpQ.png

This is the code Im using to draw the shadow

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    cardSetup();    
}

func cardSetup(){
    self.cardView.layer.masksToBounds = false;
    self.cardView.layer.cornerRadius = 4; // if you like rounded corners

    //%%% This is a little hard to explain, but basically, it lowers the performance required to build shadows.  If you don't use this, it will lag
    var path: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.cardView.layer.bounds, cornerRadius: 4)
    self.cardView.layer.shadowPath = path.CGPath

    self.cardView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-0.4, 0.4); //%%% this shadow will hang slightly down and to the right
    self.cardView.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
    self.cardView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2;




}
```

Any ideas as to what's going on?